# Regular Expression for 13 characters alphanumeric string having exactly 3 characters and 10 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a Regular Expression for 13 characters alphanumeric string having exactly 3 characters and 10 numbers.

I am trying this:

```
^(?=.*\d{10})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{3})[0-9a-zA-Z]{13}$
```

but its not working.

Comment: I am trying with ^(?=.*\d{10})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{3})[0-9a-zA-Z]{13}$ but its not working.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{10}$/`

Comment: 3 characters THEN 10 numbers, or ANY order?

Comment: @BatuZet 
Thanks for helping but /^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{10}$/ checks for 3 characters followed by 10 numbers, whereas string can have 3 characters anywhere in it.

Comment: @FrostbiteXIII 
No particular order. It can be abc0123456789 or 0abc123456789 or 0a1345b6789c i.e. it can be anything having exactly 3 characters and 10 numbers.

Comment: @user3535700 Tested here (http://www.regexr.com/) - believe my solution does what you are after. :)

Comment: For the record, where you were going wrong is that you did: look for any chars then 10 numeric; or look for any chars then 3 alpha; now make sure there are 13 alphamumeric in total. It would work fine as long as your numeric and alphas were lumped together but wouldn't allow for anything in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (with case insensitive and ^$ matches newline options set

```
(?=^[a-z0-9]{13}$)([a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*){10}
```

or

```
(?=^[a-z0-9]{13}$)([^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*){10}
```

Ensure only 13 characters in the string, and only letters or digits

Look for exactly 10 digits in the string

**EDIT** was to change from three digits to ten digits.

```
Regex Explanation

(?=^[a-z0-9]{13}$)(?:[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*){10}

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Parentheses capture
```

*Ensure line is exactly 13 characters, with only letters and digits*

```
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=^[a-z0-9]{13}$)»
   Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed) «^»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[a-z0-9]{13}»
      Exactly 13 times «{13}»
      A character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) «a-z»
      A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
   Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed) «$»
```

*Ensure there are exactly ten digits in the line*

```
Match the regular expression below «(?:[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*){10}»
   Exactly 10 times «{10}»
   Match any single character NOT in the range between “0” and “9” «[^0-9]*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
   Match any single character NOT in the range between “0” and “9” «[^0-9]*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»

Created with RegexBuddy
```

Comment: @FrostbiteXIII See my second regex example in just edited response.  I figured since the lookahead could test for both length and content, it would fail sooner on either, and might be more efficient.  In my second regex example, I only need to test for a non-digit.

Comment: Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld. Sorry deleted my comment when you rewrote it as it no longer applied! :) Good point with the efficiency - not sure whether it works better in yours or mine (not sure when it stops if it doesn't match), but given there are probably milliseconds in it, I'm sure either will work fine). ;)

Comment: might be more readable if you use the `\d` and `\D` shorthand classes (?)... certainly shorter

Comment: Although not the case in JavaScript, because in many regex flavors, \d also matches a variety of Unicode characters, I've gotten into the habit of being more specific.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the solution. Your regex works on every test case i have tried. It works perfect. But i am not able to understand its working. Can you please elaborate a little more. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3535700  See the edit to my post for a formal explanation

Answer (score 5):

If order doesn't matter, I believe this should work:

`/^(?=.{13}$)(\d*([A-Z]\d*){3})$/ig`
or
`/^(?=.{13}$)([0-9]*([a-zA-Z][0-9]*){3})$/g`

This breaks down as follows:

- `^`: Start of string
- `(?=.{13}$)`: Look ahead expression - this looks ahead to find something (in this case 13 characters then the end of a string) before going on to do the actual RegEx
- `\d*`: Find any number of 0-9 (\d is equivalent to [0-9])
- `([A-Z]\d*){3}`: Find one A-Z then any number of 0-9 (x3 to find your three alphas)
- `$`: End of string
- `i`: Ignore case
- `g`: Find global

Comment: I'm probably missing something, because it looks like it should work, but I can't get it to work on http://regexlib.com (?)

Comment: Possibly worth noting (now that I have shortened my answer significantly, thanks to @Ron), that you could just ditch the 'i' flag and have [a-zA-Z] instead of [A-Z].

Comment: @Code Jockey What string are you trying? It wasn't working for me for ages, but then I realised I was testing with 12 characters (unless it was something else as I was messing around a lot)?

Comment: `1234r67890e6c` - not sure, I count 10/3, and it seems to work with mine, which as noted is inelegant, but I'm not sure - let me know if you see something wrong with my expression or test data

Comment: Matches fine for me @Code Jockey - do you have the 'i' flag set to ignore case?

Comment: @FrostbiteXIII

Thanks for the solution. Your regex works on every test case i have tried. It works perfect. But i am not able to understand its working.
What does (\d*([A-Z]\d*){3}) this do. Can you please elaborate a little more.
Thanks again.

Comment: @user3535700:  (\d*([A-Z]\d*){3}) is the same as saying  ([0-9]*([A-Z][0-9]*){3}) if that helps? Basically it finds 3 alpha surrounded by ANY amount of numbers, eg would match 111111A111A1111A1111. To ensure the 13 characters you need the lookahead at the beginning (?=.{13}$) - this ensures the string is exactly 13 characters. So between the two you know you have a 13 character string with exactly three alpha, the rest of which are numeric. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

This is inelegant, but it works for all my tests:

```
/^(?=[\da-zA-Z]{13}$)(?=([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){3})(?!([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){4})(?=(\D*\d){10})(?!(\D*\d){11}).*$/
```

Just ask if it works for you and you want an explanation, or else please provide a test case where it does not work correctly